# Where can I get all the message from one topic using kafka java api

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

In the command line, I can use "--from-beginning" to get all the messages in one topic, but how can I get the same effort when I code a java program ,and I'm using High Level Consumer api.

Comment: It is a very good question , even me and my friend were facing same issue, i don't know why its been "closed as unclear"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while creating the consumer properties you can add

`props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");` to start reading from the beginning

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it using your method.